# Fatal error with ggplot after updating to latest Rstudio version

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, nvidia

Recently, when booting up Rstudio v1.3 Apricot Nasturtium, a message appeared in the console warning that:

> R graphics engine version 14 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed.

I installed the latest version of Rstudio (v1.4.1106, Tiger Daylily), by downloading the Ubuntu 18/Debian 10 deb file and running

`sudo apt install ~/Downloads/rstudio-1.4.1106-amd64.deb`

To test the Plots tab, I ran

`plot(sample.int(20), sample.int(20))`

which worked without problems. I then tested ggplot by running

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
test_df <- data.frame(test_x=sample.int(20), test_y=sample.int(20))
test_df %>% ggplot(aes(x=test_x, y=test_y)) + geom_point()
```

and got a fatal error with the following error message:

> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.000291:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:86] read out of range
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.000338:ERROR elf_image_reader.cc:558] missing nul-terminator
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.000475:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.003921:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.003979:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.004031:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.004084:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.004135:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.004198:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.004660:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.004711:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.005227:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.005297:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.005351:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.005412:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.005464:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.005516:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.005564:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.005617:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.005666:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.005717:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.005874:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.005925:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.005978:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.006021:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.006077:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.006124:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.006176:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.006228:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.006284:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.006336:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.006386:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.006439:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.006552:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.006614:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.008365:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
> [438609:438609:20210601,170114.011795:ERROR directory_reader_posix.cc:42] opendir: No such file or directory (2)

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Rstudio v1.4.1106 but the issue persists.
Following [this post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/ubuntu-20-04-focal-with-nvidia-card-1920x1080-resolution-rstudio-1-4-1106-crashing/98834) I tried installing nvidia 430 drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430 nvidia-settings
```

but Rstudio experiences the same fatal error when attempting ggplot commands.

My current specs are Rstudio v1.4.1106 with R v4.1.0, on a Dell XPS 15 7590 running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
The graphics card is an NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q].

Comment: I'm also having that error, a hack is to run `X11()` before running any `ggplot` code.

Comment: Not sure if that could help in your case, but when I had some issues with a too new RStudio graphics engine version I switched the graphics backend to agg (Tools - Global Options - General - Graphics - Backend), which helped in my case. Maybe worth a try. Maybe also make sure all packages are up to date, and consider giving the preview version (https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) a try to see if that fixes that issue.

Comment: re comment ^^ https://twitter.com/kevin_ushey/status/1395054942088400905

Comment: I experienced the same fatal error while running Rstudio 1.41717 on Ubuntu 20.04. Before switching the graphics backend to agg (thanks  @user12728748 for flagging that), the package ragg has to be installed. I had to run sudo apt install libtiff-dev to satisfy a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like it's an issue with ggplot and the latest version of RStudio. Currently waiting for an official fix, but in the meantime running `X11()` before each ggplot command works, as does switching the graphics backend to 'agg'.

I'm currently using the 'agg' workaround as it's easier for me than the `X11()` fix.

Comment: Any idea where I could find the 'agg' workaround on a Mac, please? I can get as far as Tools - Global Options - General, but there is no entry for Graphics.